# How to customize a HTML form on browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have a HTML form containing some input fields like textbox, labele, checkboxe, dropdown, etc. This form is being rendered in UI and we want to give an option where a user can customize this webform on the webpage itself and the resultant changes should be saved so that in next visit user can see the customized form.

Note: I have Web form already and i need to customize the same, I do not need to create a form from scratch.

Update: Below is my sample webpage form

```
form class="form-inline">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Show some code to illustrate what you've tried to make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: Please give a live example or somewhere on live code like Codepen.

Comment: @HardenRahul I have added my sample HTML

Comment: @RickvanOsta Sample HTML has been added

Comment: "Customize" can be **anything** under the sun. What do you want to let the user customize? The number of input elements? The type of each input element? Being able to remove/delete or add control groups? Being able to modify attributes to certain input fields (like `name`, `id`, `disabled`, `selected`)? Being able to change the styles or JS bindings of each input? Your question is *extremely* broad.

Comment: @Terry I want the update the size and position of the input elements. Only these two functions are required..Thanks for clarifying the options to me.

Comment: What sort of persistence methodology do you have in place?

Comment: @TezWingfield I am willing to save the updated Page Markup in Db table column

Comment: You're going to keep getting downvotes. What have you tried thus far to create either a WYSIWYG editor for the forms, or your mechanism to persist? It's really two separate, and pretty substantial, issues.

Comment: @Snowmonkey I do not have idea what to look into in Web which can solve my issue..Any keywords or scripts can be helpful for me..Please suggest.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's a start. The input field is wrapped in a resizable div, with a resize handle for width. As of 2016, this seems to be the best option for resizing text fields. When that resize handle is released, i've added an event listener that simply reports the field name and the updated size in pixels.

So you can see one possible solution, I've prototyped saving the field widths to an object in localStorage. This could as easily be done to a backend via AJAX or whatever, but it seems to me that saving an object would be the way to pass that data.

Note that this won't actually run here, as there is a limitation to the sandbox (can't get access to localStorage). To see this working, here's a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/snowMonkey/cbw7q/58/)**.

Note also, all I've done is allow the size to be adjusted. Didn't even really know where to start with the whole 'adjust the position' thing.

```js
// Uncomment the following line to reset the field widths.
//localStorage.clear()

// If we don't have a customFormSettings saved, create some defaults.
if (!localStorage.getItem("myCustomFormSettings")) {
  var myDefaultFormSettings = { 'email': '250px', 'pwd': '250px'}
  localStorage.setItem("myCustomFormSettings", JSON.stringify(myDefaultFormSettings));
};

// Whether they are custom or default, load the settings so we can
//    set the widths.
var myCustomFormSettings = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myCustomFormSettings") );

// Go through the myCustomFormSettings object, and use each property
//   to set the field width.
for (var property in myCustomFormSettings){
  $("#"+property).parent().css("width", myCustomFormSettings[property]);
}

/*****
 * When the field is resized, we need to update the object we've saved
 *   to localStorage with the field name and the new width. This same
 *   JSON object could be just as easily stored on a back-end or what
 *   have you.
 *****/
$(".resizable-input > span").on("mouseup", function(){
  // First, get the field name and width values
  var fieldName = $(this).siblings(".form-control:first").attr("id");
  var fieldWidth = $(this).parent().width()+"px";
  
  // Update the object we'll be saving with the new data.
  myCustomFormSettings[fieldName] = [fieldWidth];
  
  // And either save it to localStorage, or send it to the server.
  localStorage.setItem("myCustomFormSettings", JSON.stringify(myCustomFormSettings));
  
  console.log(myCustomFormSettings);

})
```

```css
.resizable-input {
    /* make resizable */
    overflow-x: hidden;
    resize: horizontal;
    display: inline-block;

    /* no extra spaces */
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
  
    /* default widths */
    width: 10em;
    min-width: 2em;
    max-width: 30em;
}

/* let <input> assume the size of the wrapper */
.resizable-input > input {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}

/* add a visible handle */
.resizable-input > span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    margin-left: -16px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAQAAAC1+jfqAAAAJUlEQVR4AcXJRwEAIBAAIPuXxgiOW3xZYzi1Q3Nqh+bUDk1yD9sQaUG/4ehuEAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==");
    cursor: ew-resize;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <span class="resizable-input"><input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email"><span></span></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
  <span class="resizable-input"><input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password"><span></span></span>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!. That's what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Use client side scripting, to drag and drop the controls or elements(Ex : Jquery)
Refer this link : http://jqueryui.com/draggable/
https://jqueryui.com/resizable/

In DB, Save the  Parent control name and X,Y coordinates or css info for the particular control for each user.

Whenever user login load the coordinates and css info from db and load it accordingly into the page.